Hindi movie about two sisters who fall in love with the same man
Hey would you  know the name of a movie with the same plot as Aaina but a bit different?
There is also a pageant involved but I don't remeber them having parents or grandparents around. I even think they lost their parents and have been looking after each other since. One of the sisters couldn't speak but she found her voice later when she got really angry and yelled. The sister who is going to marry the man also goes away and comes back later. But in this story the other sister stays with the man and pretends she is the sister who went away and came back earlier. The sister who pretends (who is kind of the evil sister) also threatens to commit suicide. But she dies at the end trying to kill the sister who is actually married to the man.
As you can see I only remember parts of the movie but I hope it's enough. 
I've been looking for this movie for more than a year and no one I know remembers the title. This (Aaina) is actually the closest I've come to finding something about it. It is the same plot but the other one is made around the year 2003-2004. I saw the movie for the last time in 2005 and after lending it out to someone I never saw it again.
They also have different names. I think it is Raya and Suraya or Priya and Riya (I doubt that last one but it's possible). Oh by the way, it's possible that the sisters are twins.

You are looking for Sheesha from 2005 starring Sonu Sood and Neha Dhupia where Neha played a double role. The plot matches your description. Sheesha is another word for Aaina in Hindi.

Businesswoman Sia Malhotra (Neha Dhupia) lives a wealthy lifestyle in Bangkok, along with her twin, Ria (Neha Dhupia), who is deaf and dumb due to a neurological disorder. She meets with Raj Oberoi (Sonu Sood), and both fall in love. Their endeavors to cure Ria are all in vain. Sia plans to travel to the United States to improve her business, and has no one to look after Ria. So she decides to get married to Raj so that he could move in with Ria and look after her. Raj agrees, and both obtain a marriage certificate and Sia departs for America. Sia does not know that after her return she will be a suspect in the brutal killing of a female Caucasian, Diana (Elidh MacQueen), and will not be permitted to leave Bangkok; and she will face further trauma and shock when she finds that her sister has been preying on her husband. After a confrontation between the two sisters, Ria beats Sia and leaves to Raj as Sia. She tricks him into travelling away from Sia. Soon, Raj comes to know the truth. Sia too arrives at that point. Raged with anger Ria tries to kill Sia, but Raj interrupts and Ria accidentally falls off the building. Raj tries to save her but Ria realises her folly and lets go of Raj's hands killing herself.

The name of those sister are Sia and Ria.

+1, but I don't think that the spoiler feature is necessary here since the question revealed the plot anyway (I'm also not sure why Neha Dhupia's name was in quotes).

She is actress who had performed double role, so i thought its better to highlight it.

You can always highlight text with 2 asterisks on either side (or 1 for italics).
